# Node JS - How to return response from nested function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to return a response when call a function within another function?

I have following codes -

```
// Add Category
exports.saveCategory = async function(catData, callback){

    try{
        const images = await uploadImages(catData.files);
        console.log(images); //nothing prints here
        const save = await function(catData,images){
            console.log('catdata');
            return callback({status:200,message:'test'});
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

function uploadImages(images) {
    //some stuff
    return images;
}
```

**Expected output :** I want to return name of uploaded images from **uploadImages** function and pass it to another function to save in database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only async function returns promise.Make your uploadImages function async

```
async function uploadImages(images) {
        //some stuff
        return images;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Shubh Dixit works fine but i have to correct, that async functions do **NOT** return a real Promise but async function object. These do not have a `.catch()` or `.finally()` method. He is right, that a return inside a async function object will return a `Promise.resolve()`

```
async function x() {
    return 2;
}
let value = await x();
```

returns a solved Promise with the value 2. Then the await returns the value of the resolved Promise to `value`. But if you try

```
let value = await x().catch((error)=> {console.log(error);});
```

you will recieve an error that `.catch()` is no method of x.